# int value obtained via serial is output incorrectly

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I connected an arduino uno to a raspberry via serial port. The raspberry is receiving data from a robot and sends these int values via serial to the arduino. The problem now is, when I print the values to the serial monitor the int values are split to multiple lines.

The Arduino code

```
int usbRead = 1;
int i = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()) {
    usbRead = (Serial.read() - '0');
    Serial.print("Received:");
    Serial.println(usbRead);
  }
}
```

The Python script is:

```
import time
import sys
import signal
import serial

usbCom = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

try:
    while True:
        a=robot.read("EXTRUDER")
        b = int(a)
        c=b'%d' %b
        print(c)

        usbCom.write(c)
        time.sleep( 1 )
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('interrupted')
```

The output should be

```
Received: 56
Received: 56
Received: 56
```

But I get

```
Received: 5
Received: 6
Received: 5
Received: 6
Received: 5
Received: 6
```

I just don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just a confirmation here, when you print(c) in python, does it output 56 to the console?

Comment: @BobserLuck yes the output of python is correct, i get 56

Comment: [`Serial.read()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read) returns the _first byte_ of serial incoming data. Maybe [this Q&A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/45551) is of help.

Comment: @shmee thanks for the help, it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use Serial.parseInt() to read a number sent from Serial Monitor. parseInt waits for all numeric characters of the sent text, so it blocks the execution of your sketch for a very short time until all characters are received. At higher baud rate it will be faster. If your sketch doesn't need to loop as fast as possible, then you can use it. parseInt stops at first character that is not a digit (for example a newline character) and returns the received number as long.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);     
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    long number = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println(number);
  }
}
```